# Changing parent row color based on child column value- jqWidgets

Tags: grid, jqwidget

I have a nested grid, and I am able to change the nested grid row background color based on the value of one of its columns. But I would like to also be able to change the color of the parent row.

For example: Parent:Study, Child:Site, Condition:column Status=pending. 
If a site has a status of pending, I would like to change the row color for the pending site, and also change the row color for the study the contains that pending site.

```
var cellclassname = function (row, column, value, rowdata) {
    if (rowdata.Status =="Pending") {
       return "red";
    }
}
```

The code above works for the nested grid:

```
columns: [
                          { text: '<b>Site ID</b>', datafield: 'ID', width: '15%', cellclassname: cellclassname},
                          { text: '<b>Organization Name</b>', datafield: 'SiteName', width: '70%', cellclassname: cellclassname},
                          { text: '<b>DSA</b>', datafield: 'Status', width: '15%', cellclassname: cellclassname} ]
```

but not for the parent grid:

```
columns: [
                      { text: '<b>Study Filter</b>', 
                      datafield: 'StudyName',  width: '100%', cellclassname: cellclassname }
            ]
```

How can I modify my cellclassname function so it will change the row color for the parent row as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I created a work around solution.

From the database side, I was able to generate the parent data with an extra column, which says if any of the child information has a pending, then the parent study will also have a pending status. So when generating the grid, I was able to color the parent row based on that information, and I made the status column hidden.

I am still curious to know how I could have done it using the jqwidgets functions instead of modifying the source data.